# Control before setting a boolean?

Tags: java, boolean, controls

Sorry if this is a silly question but I'm kinda new in java programming.

I have a boolean stored in a Thread and I don't know if it is true or false.

I have a method `setBooleanTrue()` that set the boolean `true`, but what if the boolean is already `true`? It will set the boolean again to `true`?

For this reason I want to ask you if I should add the following control:

```
if(!testboolean)
    testboolean=true;
```

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, you want to toggle the boolean?

Comment: No. What should be the problem if `true` is overridden with `true`?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa to avoid an unnecessary set.

Comment: @Jens No problem at all. Just to avoid an unnecessary set.

Comment: Don't worry about the previous value, it will dissapear without pain. And the condition would probably take more process than the actual setting

Comment: @Clara then you have an unnecessary condition check

Comment: I think that it takes mor effort (processing) to check first and then set the boolean, rather then just overwrite it

Comment: @AxelH that was indeed my question. So the condition would take more time than the actual setting?

Comment: @Clara probably, no evidence here, but that is an unnecessary check for a primitive value. With instance that could take more resource, I would rethink this but here, don't bother. Your code would grow really fast if you start to check every value in a setter

Comment: @AxelH, would be the same for a reference type like enum?

Comment: Only the reference would change since enums are constants so don't worry. I was thinking about a value that would need a constructor call, without expressing the idea completly. Once the instance is already created, don't bother, the hardest as been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in the amount of time saved by adding the conditional, have a look at this:

Below I have written out both versions of your code, and the corresponding generated java bytecode.

```
 boolean b = true;
 if(!b)
      b=true;

 0: iconst_1
 1: istore_1
 2: iload_1
 3: ifne
 6: iconst_1
 7: istore_1
 8: return


 boolean b = true;
 b=true;

 0: iconst_1
 1: istore_1
 2: iconst_1
 3: istore_1
 4: return
```

As you can see, the direct reassignment of the `boolean` generates less bytecode.

At first, this may seem like the answer.  Unfortunately, it isn't that simple.  See runtime environments do this fancy thing called [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array).  If a line of code is being run continuously, the JVM will attempt to "predict" the outcome of the conditional.

This can be a really good thing, or a really bad thing.  Your expected values of the `boolean`, the number of times it is to be checked in rapid succession and whether it is likely to remain a certain value through many calls will determine whether you should add the conditional statement or not.

Answer (score -1):

when you assign a value to any variable, the variables current value doesn't get evaluated, it just sets the variable to the value you want. So there's no need to check if a bool is true or false before setting it to true. if its true it will stay true, if its false it will become true.